# Sqlite Query to remove duplicates from one column. Removal depends on the second column

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, subquery, sql-delete

Please have a look at the following data example:

[image]

In this table, I have multiple columns. There is no PRIMARY KEY, as per the image I attached, there are a few duplicates in STK_CODE. Depending on the (min) column, I want to remove duplicate rows.

According to the image, one stk_code has three different rows. Corresponding to these duplicate stk_codes, value in (min) column is different, I want to keep the row which has minimum value in (min) column.

I am very new at sqlite and I am dealing with (-lsqlite3) to join cpp with sqlite.

Is there any way possible?

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Please [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table has `rowid` as primary key.
Use it to get the `rowid`s that you don't want to delete:

```
DELETE FROM comparison
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
  SELECT rowid
  FROM comparison
  GROUP BY STK_CODE
  HAVING (COUNT(*) = 1 OR MIN(CASE WHEN min > 0 THEN min END))
)
```

This code uses `rowid` as a [bare column](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing) and a documented feature of SQLite with which when you use `MIN()` or `MAX()` aggregate functions the query returns that row which contains the min or max value.

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5bfcd931f15a45318b64eeca0d46dd7a).

Comment: I am thankful to what you sent, it worked in every single case. Thanks a lot